# Xcode6(Swift) HMSegmentedControlの使い方

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode6

SwiftでもObj-Cでも開発経験がないため、まずは下記ページのコードをそのまま実装してみようと試みています。
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/ios_oss_hmsegmentedcontrol/

42〜45行目を除いて、Swiftコードへ置き換えて実装できました。
42〜45行目は「setIndexChangeBlockというメソッドがない」という旨のエラー出るなど、記述方法が分からなかったので一旦コメントアウトしています。
その状態で実行可能なのですが、タブを選択してもScrollViewが変わらず"実行結果"のようにはなりません。

Swiftで記述する場合はここに載っている以外にも記述が必要なのか、それとも42〜45行目をなんとかSwiftで書かなければならないのか、教えてください。
42〜45行目のSwiftでの記述方法もご教示いただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

42〜45行目のSwiftでの記述方法は、以下で動作するはずです。

```
let segmentControls = HMSegmentedControl(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
self.view.addSubview(segmentControls)
segmentControls.sectionTitles = ["1","2","3"]
segmentControls.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
let blockVariable :IndexChangeBlock = {(index:Int) -> Void in
    println(index)
}
segmentControls.indexChangeBlock = blockVariable
```

Comment: iwashiroさんの回答を参考にして IndexChangeBlock を実装することができました！

その中で scrollRectToVisible() を実行することでタブの選択に合わせて ScrollView も切り替わるようになりました。

回答ありがとうございました。